# For a Lebesgue integrable function $f$, the map $t\mapsto\int \chi_{A+t}f(x) dx $ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $ f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $A $ is  Borel subset of $R$. Show that the mapping $t$ to $\int \chi_{A+t}f(x) dx $ is continuous from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

---

I try first by taking A as an interval. I think it works in case this case but I could not figure out when A is general Borel set. Please help me out.

Comment: If $A$ is an intervall you can use dominated convergence, but that won't work in general. Hint: For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a continuous function $g$ with compact support such that $||f-g||_1<\epsilon$.

Comment: yea i Know that fact but how would i apply here?

Comment: Show the result holds for $g$. Deduce that it holds within $\epsilon$ for $f$...

Comment: The fact that you find the problem "very nice" is not very informative and it should not appear in the title.